# Problem on logarithm

Tags: logarithms

$$\mbox{If}\ \log_{2a}\left(a\right) = x,\ \log_{3a}\left(2a\right) = y,\ \log_{4a}\left(3a\right) = z.\quad
\mbox{Then, what is the value of}\ xyz-2yz\,?.
$$ Not exactly able to solve it any further.

Comment: Do you know about [change of base identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may write
$$
x=\log_{2a}a=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(2a)},\quad y=\log_{3a}(2a)=\frac{\log(2a)}{\log(3a)},\quad z=\log_{4a}(3a)=\frac{\log(3a)}{\log(4a)}
$$ giving
$$
xyz-2yz=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(2a)}\cdot\frac{\log(2a)}{\log(3a)}\cdot\frac{\log(3a)}{\log(4a)}-2\cdot\frac{\log(2a)}{\log(3a)}\cdot\frac{\log(3a)}{\log(4a)}
$$ that is

> $$
> xyz-2yz=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(4a)}-\frac{2 \cdot \log(2a)}{\log(4a)}.
> $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please solve it further I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Ujjwal How would you simplify $\log(a)-2 \cdot \log(2a)$?

Comment: That is what I want to ask

Comment: @Ujjwal Ok, how would you write differently $\log(2a)$?

Comment: Log 2 + log a? Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, then $\log(a)-2 \cdot \log(2a)$ gives ...

Comment: I got the answer just one last question..i know that loga+logb = loga. b but what is loga-logb=?? Is it -loga.b?

Comment: Finally $xyz-2yz=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(4a)}-\frac{2 \cdot \log(2a)}{\log(4a)}=\frac{-\log(4a)}{\log(4a)}=-1.$

Comment: Thanks brother. I'm gonna upvote your answer.

Comment: @Ujjwal You are welcome.

Comment: i know that loga+logb = loga. b but what is loga-logb=?? Is it -loga.b?

Comment: We rather have $\log a - \log b= \log (\frac{a}{b})$.

Comment: After taking LCM shouldn't it be like $\frac{log a - 2(log a+ log 2)}{log 4a}$

Comment: Yes, this is OK.